# java org.joda.time.DateTime illegal pattern

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

This is my string

> 2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

I am changing it to date time object using `org.joda.time.DateTime`

This is my code

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat
                .forPattern("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z");
        DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
```

I got exception

> Illegal pattern component: T

So the `T` and `.000Z` are always there, how can I format ?

Comment: Go to the [documentation page](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), open your search bar in the browser and write "escape". Read what it found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the `T`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000Z");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
System.out.println(dt);
```

Also, not too sure why you want to enforce the millis to be `000`. If they are always `000`, you probably should not include them at all.